# DataTable.compute() Value was either too large or too small for an Int32

Tags: c#

So I want to calculate something from a string, like this:

```
var s = dt.Compute(exps[0].Replace("x", i.ToString()), "");
```

and when exps[0] is `x*x*x` then I get this error: `Value was either too large or too small for an Int32`

Actually, it worked before with any numbers, I don't know what's wrong.

`i` is an `int` in a `for` loop and `dt` is a `DataTable`.

Comment: You can [use doubles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29569213/1997232) instead of ints.

Comment: Thank you @Sinatr addig `.0` to the end of the string worked.

Answer (score 1):

When you're doing `x³`, it doesn't take much to overflow an `int`; `1290` is the largest thing you can cube. So... if `i` is more than that, this is expected. You could try ensuring that the column is a `long` - that'll give you a little more room, but for very big numbers you'll need to switch to `double` or `decimal` (noting that they lose precision in the tail).