# Data.DataTable().Compute not evaluating big number in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, datatable

I want to evaluate this expression

```
IIF((1602 * 2136 * 1601) <> 0, 100 * ((1601 * 2133 *  1601)/(1602 * 2136 * 1601)), -1),
```

I am getting exception->

> System.OverflowException: 'Value is either too large or too small for Type 'Int32'.'

```
newFormulaString = IIF((1602 * 2136 * 1601) <> 0, 100 * ((1601 * 2133 *  1601)/(1602 * 2136 * 1601)), -1)

OutputDtbl(i - 1) = Convert.ToInt64(New Data.DataTable().Compute(newFormulaString, Nothing))
```

Comment: Have you seen [DataTable Compute Value is too large or too small for type Int32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29569213/datatable-compute-value-is-too-large-or-too-small-for-type-int32)?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, Thank u so much, I need to replace 1602.0 in my expression using regex, i am unable to change for entire expression at once in vb.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expressio0n `1602 * 2136 * 1601` is more than 5 billions. `Int32` has an approximate maximum of 2 billions.

Use the `Long` type instead of `Integer`. `Long` has a maximum of ~ `9.2E+18`. You can specify a `Long` number with `L`. E.g. `1602L`. If you are using variables in your real expression, you can convert them to `Long` by multiplying them with `1L` as in `1L * x * y * z`.

Comment: Thank u so much, but i am getting 1602 as string, i tried this                                
Dim offSetvalue As Long = CLng(values(5, foundCol) - values(1, foundCol)), I am unable to append L for 1602, can u pls help me out in this

Comment: tried with multiplying with 1L but it did not work for me

Comment: It would help to see your real code. The "L" works only in VB code, not in a string that you convert to `Long` e.g. with `CLng`. Converting the strings with `CLng` before doing the math should work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rewrite FWIW

```
    ' rewritten
    '  change variable names
    Const num1 As Long = 1602L * 2136L * 1601L
    Const num2 As Long = 1601L * 2133L * 1601L
    Const divNums As Long = num2 \ num1

    Dim rslt As Long = If(num1 <> 0L, 100L * divNums, -1L)
```